# JetBrains WebStorm ignores Indentation Settings

Tags: webstorm

In `Settings > Code Style > JavaScript` I've set `Tab size` and `Indent` to 4. Why is WebStorm still ignoring these settings, as you can see in the preview window:

[image]

What settings could override these?

Comment: If you have EditorConfig plugin enabled (which should be by default) and have `.editorconfig` files in your project (or maybe even above the project root) then settings from there will override your Code Style (which is expected as this is the whole point of such plugin). Please check that moment.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. However, as I'm evaluating the product, I wonder what's the point of that behaviour? It has written "confusion" all over it. Why is updating the settings not updating the `.editorconfig` file? If you got an answer to this, I'll accept ...

Comment: 1) Please check what `.editorconfig` files are for -- they meant to be editor-independent. 2) You are editing Code Style settings and not actual EditorConfig settings 3) With `.editorconfig` you can do things that are not possible with Code Style (e.g. different right margins / trailing white space handling per different file types, even if they are not supported by Code Style)

Comment: I see, thank you. It doesn't improve the usability of the product, though, if a plugin overrides the default Code Style settings without the IDE telling you so.

Comment: 4) IDE should be showing you the notice (using light GUI theme it would be green bar on top of the editor window) where it would tell that "editorconfig file overriding your Code Style settings" -- I'm just not sure if it's available in WebStorm v11 . .or is it since v12 only. 5) If you go one level up in your settings (just `Code Style` and not `Code Style > JavaScript` as on your screenshot) you will see mention of this moment as well 6) You may file a Feature Request ticket for such "update `.editorconfig` file" idea -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: ah thanks. now that makes it clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have EditorConfig plugin enabled (which should be by default) and have `.editorconfig` files in your project (or maybe even above the project root) then settings from there will override your Code Style (which is expected as this is the whole point of such plugin).

---

Why such behaviour? What can be done?

1. Please check what `.editorconfig` files are for -- they meant to be editor-independent. It meant to override your internal settings to provide consistency across different IDEs/editors used without the need to configure your IDE/editor just for this project/folder
2. You are editing Code Style settings and not actual EditorConfig settings
3. With `.editorconfig` you can do things that are not currently possible with Code Style (e.g. different right margins / trailing white space handling per different file types, even if they are not supported by Code Style)
4. Code Style is applied to the whole project (all files) while `.editorconfig` can be configured differently for each sub-folder and even have exclusions.
5. IDE should be showing you the notice (using light GUI theme it would be green bar on top of the editor window) where it would tell that "Settings may be overridden by EditorChonfig." -- I'm just not sure if it's available in `WebStorm v11`, or is it since `v12` only.
6. If you go one level up in your settings (just `Code Style` and not `Code Style > JavaScript` as on your screenshot) you will see mention of this moment as well
7. You may file Feature Request ticket for such "update .editorconfig file while editing Code Style" idea at JetBrains' [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB).

### Example `.editorconfig` file:

```
# Editor configuration, see http://editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
end_of_line = lf
indent_size = 2
indent_style = space
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
max_line_length = off
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

Comment: @Top-Master Regarding your edit: you can export IDE's whole Code Style into `.editorconfig` file even right now, just manually: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-code-style.html#EditorConfig . But if it's for "those few native rules only" or make it automatic then yes, not currently available.