# WebStorm auto-indent inconsistent with indentation settings

Tags: javascript, webstorm, indentation, jetbrains-ide, auto-indent

I want to auto-indent an entire JavaScript file in WebStorm, and in my settings I have the following:

[image: indent settings]

The problem is that when I use the menu `Code -> Auto-Indent Lines` or `Code -> Reformat Code` the indentation level remains at 2.

Is there a setting somewhere I am missing? I don't want to be inconsistent with the coding standards put in place.

Comment: Is there anything in Code Style above the JavaScript menu item? Could it be that the menus use the global setting?

Comment: @Sarcoma nothing that I can see

Comment: When you open a file wifh an indentation level inconsistent with your IDE settings, a yellow bar pops up saying something to the effect of "The indentation for this file is wrong, what should I do?" IIRC it gives you options like "ignore" and "fix indentation [to be consistent with my settings]." If you click ignore it will ignore the indentation inconsistency for this file permanently. Do you remember ever doing that?

Comment: @Rice Do you have `.editorconfig` in your project? Settings from there will overwrite your code style settings (and that is expected behaviour). Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37632620/783119 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/35746240/783119

Comment: @LazyOne It seems .editorconfig was indeed the culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the .editorconfig file located in the root of the project directory. Although I can't recall receiving a warning, the settings in that file overwrote the Webstorm settings, and changing them to the desired indentations resulted in the desired result.